# Degree of the syzygy bundle of a curve of genus 3

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, syzygies

Let X be an hyperelliptic curve of genus 3,  its canonical sheaf, and M the syzygy bundle of .
What is the degree of M?

Comment: What do you mean by the syzygy bundle here?

Comment: Presumably $M$ is the kernel of the surjective homomorphism to $\omega$ from the "trivial" vector bundle of $H^0(X,\omega_X)$.  So $M$ has degree $2-2g$, i.e., $-4$ in this case.

Comment: But why is \omega  globally generated?

Comment: For all smooth projective curves of genus $g>0$, the dualizing  sheaf is globally generated via Serre duality and chasing a long exact sequence.